# Invalid Index to a scalar variable

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I have a calculate function which returns 2 values.

```
def calculate(argument1,argument2......):
      something
      something
    return( a,b)
```

when I'm trying to call its elements
by `m[0]` or `m[1]` and appending them to an empty list by :

```
m=Calculate(str(DT), str(Train_till_date), int(fcst_mnth), int(fcst_yr))
mfcst=m[0]
asale=m[1]
```

I'm getting an error :

See Image: [image]

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/ankit/SKUs/Important/GUI & Loop_test.py", line 63, in get
    mfcst=m[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

How do i save the values given by the calculate function and append those in 2 different lists?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `Calculate` *always* returns a tuple of two values? Based on your error, it looks like it actually returned a NumPy scalar and you tried to index it.

Comment: Check the function to see if there are multiple `return` statements. They all need to return two values.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yes it always return 2 values

Comment: @Barmar, There is only  1 return statement. The funny thing is if i run this calaculate function in a new .py file the m[0] and m[1] comands actually returns the value

Comment: Unless you can post a [mcve] (not pseudo-code with "something something") there's no way for us to tell what's really going wrong. The code you posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change this function to:

```
def calculate(argument1,argument2......):
      something
      something
    return a,b

mfcst, asale = Calculate(str(DT), str(Train_till_date), int(fcst_mnth), int(fcst_yr))
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This is the usual way to write it, but why doesn't it work as he did it?

Comment: This answer is no different at all from what the OP's trying to do.

Comment: Looking at this, i thought it should work but sadly, it doesn't

Comment: Now, it's giving me an error : cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object

Comment: @Ankit Gupta I believe Barmar and Matias Cicero are correct.  Somewhere in side your Calculate() function you’re must have a second “return” statement that does not return two variables, but only one. You should review your code or post the full code for your Calculate() function.